# Flutter: Autocomplete Textfield not working with custom data type

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to build a text field with autocomplete feature. And I'm using [AutoComplete TextField](https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield#-) package.

I have Users model class with `fromMap` and `toMap` methods. There's function which retrieves users form database and returns list of users `List<Users>`.

Here's the code which builds autocomplete field:

```
AutoCompleteTextField searchTextField = AutoCompleteTextField<Users>(
    key: key,
    clearOnSubmit: false,
    suggestions: users,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0),
      hintText: "Search Name",
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    itemFilter: (item, query) {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
    },
    itemSorter: (a, b) {
      return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    },
    itemSubmitted: (item) {
      setState(() {
        searchTextField.textField.controller.text = item.name;
      });
    },
    itemBuilder: (context, item) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            item.name,
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
```

**Q.** Am I missing something or doing wrong?

**NOTE:**

1. The `users` object have list of users in correct format, I've printed to verify that.

Comment: and your question is ...? `"Am I missing something or doing wrong?"` does not really say much, does it crash? if so, post the stacktrace, if not, whats not working?

Comment: It doesn't crash, and also don't show expected results. There are about 5 users with starting letter `A`, when I type `A` then it is suppose to show list of users starting with `A`, but it doesn't show anything. And there isn't any error in console. However when I type something and tap outside the field, it shows this error `W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5489): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection

Exception caught by gesture 
The method 'where' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: where(Closure: (Users) => bool)`

Comment: you are using https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield? i had a lot of problems with it, that disappeared when i switched to https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead (much better documented package)

Comment: thanks, I'll use that. 1. How can I remove a package completely from project? (wanted to remove `autocomplete_textfield` package) 2. How do I get town name at the end?

Comment: 1. remove it from `pubspec.yaml` file, 2. data is taken from sqflite?

Comment: thanks for the `1`, and I know how to get it from DB. I was trying to ask, how can I display using `flutter_typeahead`? (username, town) Town name should stick to the right side, like `trailing` does in `ListTile`

Comment: you have `itemBuilder` so return whatever `Widget` you want

Comment: @pskink how do I set default value for `TypeAheadFormField`? I tried `initialValue` parameter but it throws an error `'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart': Failed assertion: line 289 pos 13: 'initialValue == null || textFieldConfiguration.controller == null': is not true.`

Comment: it means that you cannot have both attributes at the same time

Comment: alright, is it possible to set initial value somehow?

Comment: yes, by using the controller

Comment: sure, your welcome, post a self answer then...

Comment: you have helped a lot so you deserve some credit, please post an answer and I'll accept that, if possible. If you didn't then I'll post an answer.

Comment: feel free to post a self answer - you did the real job - i only posted some comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned,

> you are using [autocomplete_textfield](http://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield)? i had a lot of problems with it, that disappeared when i switched to [flutter_typeahead](http://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) (much better documented package)

So I considered his suggestion, and move to `flutter_typeahead` package.

```
final TextEditingController _typeAheadController = TextEditingController();

List<String> usersList;

//find and create list of matched strings
List<String> _getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = List();

    matches.addAll(usersList);

    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
}

//gets user list from db
void _getUsersList() async {
    usersList = await databaseHelper.getUsersList();
}


//the above code is defined in the class, before build method


//builds the text field
TypeAheadFormField(
  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
      controller: _typeAheadController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select a User'),
  suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
    return _getSuggestions(pattern);
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(suggestion),
    );
  },
  transitionBuilder: (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
    return suggestionsBox;
  },
  onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
    _typeAheadController.text = suggestion;

  },
  validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
      ? 'Please select a user...'
      : null,
  onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _name = val),
),



//function that pulls data from db and create a list, defined in db class
//not directly relevant but it may help someone
Future<List<String>> getUsersList() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;

    final usersData = await db.query("users");

    return usersData.map((Map<String, dynamic> row) {
      return row["name"] as String;
    }).toList();
}
```

**PS:** One thing I miss about `autocomplete_textfield` is the way that we can pass multiple parameters, as we can inherit from our own custom model e.g `user` model. I know it is possible with this, but I'm new to this so still unable to make it work! :(

Comment: you dont need `getUsersList()`method  - just change `_getSuggestions(String pattern)` to return `db.query("users", where: "name like %?%", whereArgs: [pattern])` - thats all

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work. I tried `return await db.query('users', where: "name LIKE %?%", whereArgs: [pattern])` and it throwed `Database Exception` so I switched to `return await db
        .rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$pattern%'");` But now it throws `Error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'`. I also tried to define `_getSuggestions` as `FutureOr<List<dynamic>>` but it throws different error: `type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.

Comment: @pskink I noticed something weird about `typeahead`. If I define initial value like this `_typeAheadController.text = "California";` then re-selecting any other value in the form doesn't work. When we delete default value and type any other value then it just shows for split of second and changes back to default value. Do you have any idea, what could be wrong? **NOTE:** if we remove initial value then it just works fine.

Comment: and i have no idea what you mean by `"re-selecting any other value"`

Comment: I'll try that `name LIKE ?`, and `re-selecting any other value` means when we try to select any value; other than initial/default value in the form.

Comment: thanks dear, it worked. I was doing it wrong, I was setting value inside `build` method, that's why it wasn't working!

Comment: @Alena  TypeAheadFormField selection is not working on flutter web.Actual problem is in onSuggestionSelected on flutter web.U can not select an item.Any solution??

Comment: @Alena Use GestureDetector inside itemBuilder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475883/typeahead-textfield-in-flutter-web/75309031#75309031  to work it on web

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, the solution was to put a bool and show a CircularProgressIndicator until all the data in the list is loaded, and thus rendering the AutoCompleteTextField

Ex.:

```
  _isLoading
                   ? CircularProgressIndicator ()
                   : searchTextField = AutoCompleteTextField <User> (your component here)
```